# Is there a way to get the location every x minutes, even when there are no changes?

Tags: android, location

I am using Android Studio. I use locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...) to get the location.

I want to do something like this:

```
//print location every 5 minutes
12:10am lat=10.23652 long=21.25441
12:15am lat=10.23652 long=21.25441
12:20am lat=15.21456 long=58.21452
12:25am lat=12.24752 long=27.24587
12:30am lat=12.24752 long=27.24587
12:35am lat=12.24752 long=27.24587
...
```

I'm not interested in knowing if the location changed, I just want to print it every x minutes.

Comment: Just pack your code into a new thread and call it every 5 minutes.

Comment: Do you need it in background too  when the app is closed ?

Comment: yes, i need it in background

Answer (score 0):

A solution could incorporate a Handler with a postDelayed. **It is important to remove any Callbacks!**

Try something like this:

```
private boolean continueLoop = true;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

private void startLocationManager() {
    try{
        Log.d(TAG, "startLocationManager - Started");
        // here the delay (in this example it is effectively the interval)
        int minutes = 5;
        int delay = 1000 * 60 * minutes;
        myHandler.postDelayed(mAutoLocationManager, delay);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private Runnable mAutoLocationManager = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(continueLoop){
            // preform the scan for the location coordinates
            startYourLocationCoordinates();

            //re-trigger the call to start a new interval
            startLocationManager();
        {
    }
};

// Make certain that you remove the callback when you leave the activity -- maybe in onPause()
private void stopAutoDownloadManager(){
    try{
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(mAutoLocationManager);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```